# My Excel workbook with custom formulas breaks when I use other workbooks simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

I´m using an Excel workbook with a custom formula for taking a value from the previous worksheet. I use this formula like `INDIRECT(SHEETNAME(SHEET(A1)-1)&"!A1")`, so `SHEET(A1)` returns the current sheet number, and `SHEETNAME(SHEET(A1)-1)` returns the name of the previous sheet, then I use `INDIRECT` to take the value A1 from that previous sheet.

Here is the code for the custom sheetname formula:

```
Function SHEETNAME(number As Long) As String
    SHEETNAME = Sheets(number).Name
End Function
```

The problem is that when I use other workbook at the same time, the mentioned command returns `#VALUE!`.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Consider including the workbook name...

Comment: `Sheets` without a qualifier always assumes `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Also, consider using `Worksheets` instead, as `Sheets` includes both `Worksheets` and `Charts`. Especially if you are referring to them by index.

Comment: @braX Thanks. That's good to know. I never use charts, so assumed they were synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

You should always fully qualify.

So instead of `Sheets(number).Name`, try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(number).Name`

Not doing so can lead to bugs that are difficult to diagnose.
I would always suggest avoiding "ActiveWorkbook" unless you specifically need it.